# How to write an entire trajectory into a single PDB file?

Tags: computational-chemistry, software, proteins, molecular-mechanics, molecular-dynamics

I have a trajectory (few frames) that I want to stack together and build a single PDB. I thought either to use VMD or [MDAnalysis](https://www.mdanalysis.org/docs/documentation_pages/coordinates/PDB.html) library.

With VMD if I do [`atomselect`](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/vmd-1.7.1/ug/node108.html) it takes a frame identifier as an argument. With MDAnalysis I saw this:

```
with MDAnalysis.Writer("all.pdb", multiframe=True) as pdb:
    for ts in u.trajectory:
        pdb.write(u)
```

However, I am not sure how to use it in a complete script.

Comment: Not only is your edit asking a different question, it's not the right question. That PDB file doesn't have multiple "trajectories" or frames. It's a protein with quaternary structure, where each subunit is separated by a `TER` card. You should ask a separate question about how to split apart PDB files.

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon I see, that was my original problem. I created a new [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88096/how-to-manipulate-pdb-to-have-a-single-frame-with-all-the-structure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import MDAnalysis

# file formats are automatically deduced; this is a standard topology and binary
# (NetCDF) trajectory from AMBER
topology = 'peptide_1.prmtop'
trajectory = '02_peptide_1_equil_NVT.nc'
u = MDAnalysis.Universe(topology, trajectory)

with MDAnalysis.Writer("all.pdb", multiframe=True) as pdb:
    for ts in u.trajectory:
        pdb.write(u)
```

One thing that may be important: I see lots of warnings when trying to use Python 3, so 2.7 is probably better at this point.