# How to unify all the subunits in a PDB file?

Tags: software, proteins

A PDB may contain a [`TER`](https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/docs/UsersGuide/tutorials/pdbintro.html) token. For example, [hemoglobin](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore.do?structureId=1a3n) has 4 subunits separated by a `TER` identifier.

If we take hemoglobin's [biological assembly pdb file](https://files.rcsb.org/download/1A3N.pdb1.gz) we see:

```
ATOM   1067  NH1 ARG A 141      26.176   8.362  17.810  1.00 11.11           N  
ATOM   1068  NH2 ARG A 141      24.650   9.068  16.200  1.00 13.86           N  
ATOM   1069  OXT ARG A 141      26.697  14.784  20.720  1.00 10.99           O  
TER    1070      ARG A 141                                                      
ATOM   1071  N   HIS B   2       3.670 -13.643  19.447  1.00 38.58           N  
ATOM   1072  CA  HIS B   2       2.695 -14.734  19.744  1.00 32.83           C  
ATOM   1073  C   HIS B   2       1.379 -14.140  20.199  1.00 30.79           C
```

Is there an easy way to merge all the subunits into a single [VMD](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/) frame?

Comment: I still think you should be more careful with your wording. The PDB file is a single frame as far as VMD is concerned. Do you want to remove the quaternary structure completely?

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon there are 4 subunits I want all of them to be in a single name. I am not sure what do you mean by removing the quaternary structure.

Comment: In a PDB file with the TER entries like this, there is both a chemical and textual representation of the quaternary structure (the subunits). If you remove them, of course the protein still has subunits, so there is some chemical structure, but the textual representation is lost.

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon what's a textual representation?

Comment: I mean the PDB file. It's the text format describing something chemical.

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon ah ok. I am ok that some information will be lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about residue and atom numbering, which you probably do, then `sed '/^TER/d' < 1A3N.pdb > 1A3N_combined.pdb` will do. Since atom entries must be reordered, it looks like MDAnalysis will strip the `TER` entries automatically:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import MDAnalysis


u = MDAnalysis.Universe('1A3N.pdb')

with MDAnalysis.Writer('1A3N_combined.pdb') as writer:
    writer.write(u)
```

So,

```
ATOM   1067  NH1 ARG A 141      26.176   8.362  17.810  1.00 11.11           N
ATOM   1068  NH2 ARG A 141      24.650   9.068  16.200  1.00 13.86           N
ATOM   1069  OXT ARG A 141      26.697  14.784  20.720  1.00 10.99           O
TER    1070      ARG A 141
ATOM   1071  N   HIS B   2       3.670 -13.643  19.447  1.00 38.58           N
ATOM   1072  CA  HIS B   2       2.695 -14.734  19.744  1.00 32.83           C
ATOM   1073  C   HIS B   2       1.379 -14.140  20.199  1.00 30.79           C
```

becomes

```
ATOM   1067  NH1 ARG A 141      26.176   8.362  17.810  1.00 11.11      A    N
ATOM   1068  NH2 ARG A 141      24.650   9.068  16.200  1.00 13.86      A    N
ATOM   1069  OXT ARG A 141      26.697  14.784  20.720  1.00 10.99      A    O
ATOM   1070  N   HIS B   2       3.670 -13.643  19.447  1.00 38.58      B    N
ATOM   1071  CA  HIS B   2       2.695 -14.734  19.744  1.00 32.83      B    C
ATOM   1072  C   HIS B   2       1.379 -14.140  20.199  1.00 30.79      B    C
```

where there are now chain IDs in the last column. See how this doesn't renumber residues? Modify the script; `resids` is a property, so the in-place object mutation works properly:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import numpy as np
import MDAnalysis


u = MDAnalysis.Universe('1A3N.pdb')
u.residues.resids = np.arange(1, 1 + len(u.residues.resids))

with MDAnalysis.Writer('1A3N_combined.pdb') as writer:
    writer.write(u)
```

Finally:

```
ATOM   1067  NH1 ARG A 141      26.176   8.362  17.810  1.00 11.11      A    N
ATOM   1068  NH2 ARG A 141      24.650   9.068  16.200  1.00 13.86      A    N
ATOM   1069  OXT ARG A 141      26.697  14.784  20.720  1.00 10.99      A    O
ATOM   1070  N   HIS B 142       3.670 -13.643  19.447  1.00 38.58      B    N
ATOM   1071  CA  HIS B 142       2.695 -14.734  19.744  1.00 32.83      B    C
ATOM   1072  C   HIS B 142       1.379 -14.140  20.199  1.00 30.79      B    C
```

Comment: Will it still be possible to refer/select only one subunit out of the four?

Comment: If you have a tool that selects the chain ID, I believe so.

Comment: I mean using vmd.

Comment: It works. For "Selected Atoms" under "Graphical Representations", switch from `all` to `chain A` or B, C, D, etc.